# No me reconoce la propiedad db - PHP

Tags: php, rutas, router

al requerir mi base de datos en esta hoja la propiedad db me sale en rojo adjunto captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la conexión db.

```
<?php

 class db{
    private $host="localhost";
    private $dbname="users";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password="";
    public function conexion(){
        try {
            $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname".$this->dbname,$this->user,$this->password);
            return $PDO;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();

        }
    }
 }
```

Como puedo corregir este error o requerir este db de manera correcta, tengo poco conocimiento en PHP. Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda.

Comment: Has requerido `db.php` pero no declaras `$this->db`. Hay varias soluciones, una puede ser un extends en la clase hija: `class UserModel extends db` y `$this->db = $this->conexion();` Pero eso puede variar dependiendo la arquitectura de tu proyecto, porque también podrías hacer `$db_obj = new db(); $this->db = $db_obj->conexion();` Por lo tanto es pregunta basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 1):

En tu actual clase `UserModel` no puedes usar `$this` para alcanzar a la base de datos, porque `UserModel` no extiende de la clase `db` (ni tiene por qué extender de ella).

Todo depende de la arquitectura / patrón que quieras implementar. Lo tuyo parece un patrón MVC, si quieres, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://github.com/daveh/php-mvc) (aunque hay más posibilidades). Ahí, en el **`Core`** hay una clase `Model` que es la que conecta a la base de datos y en **`App`**, dentro de `Models` tienes los modelos distintos, los cuales extienden de `\Core\Model`, y así, tienes acceso a la conexión desde los distintos modelos.

Te mostraré la única forma en que actualmente podrás acceder a tu conexión, con lo que tienes ahora, subrayando que esto no es lo deseable y que deberías organizar mejor tu estructura inspirándote en algún ejemplo como el antes citado u otro.

Convendría también que uses espacios de nombre y autoloader, para evitar los `include` y los `require` por todos lados.

Modificaremos ligeramente la clase `db`, retornando `null` cuando haya error, así podremos verificar si hay conexión o no.

```
<?php

 class db{
    private $host="localhost";
    private $dbname="users";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password="";
    public function conexion(){
        try {
            $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname".$this->dbname,$this->user,$this->password);
            return $PDO;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return null;

        }
    }
 }
```

En `UserModel` pondremos una propiedad para la conexión, y un constructor. Esto hará que la clase obtenga una instancia de la conexión cada vez que crees una instancia de `UserModel` y que puedas usar esa conexión en los diferentes métodos como obtener todos los usuarios, u obtener el usuario por su id, etc.

```
<?php
 require_once('config/db.php');
 class UserModel{
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct() {
        $db=new db();
        $this->pdo=$db->conexion();
    }

    public function getAll(){
        /*
            Puedes prescindir del if
            a mi me gusta verificar todo
        */
        if($this->pdo) {
            $query=$this->pdo->prepare(....);
            //Resto del código
        } else {
            //No hay conexión
        }
    }

    public function get($id){
        if($this->pdo) {
            $query=$this->pdo->prepare(....);
            //Resto del código
        } else {
            //No hay conexión
        }
    }
}
```